# How to parse MariaDB version banner?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, versioning

I encountered this form of MariaDB DB version via banner:
**5.5.5-10.3.38-MariaDB-log**

What is the version of the MariaDB?

Is it 5.5.5 or 10.3.38?

If one of them, what is the meaning of the other? (I thought about MySQL -> MariaDB things)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601304/what-does-the-first-part-of-the-mariadb-version-string-mean

Comment: Thank you @GeraldSchneider . This answers the question.

Comment: Your version is 10.3.38; seel the link for the meaning of the other.